# sagemaker - construct model from tar.gz file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have trained a sagemaker model successfully and the `model.tar.gz` file is on s3.

Now I want to "reconstruct" the model from that file and then deploy it. I used the following code:

```
containers = {'us-west-2': '174872318107.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/factorization-machines:latest',
              'us-east-1': '382416733822.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/factorization-machines:latest',
              'us-east-2': '404615174143.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/factorization-machines:latest',
              'eu-west-1': '438346466558.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/factorization-machines:latest'}


fm = sagemaker.model.Model(model_s3_path, containers['eu-west-1'], role=sagemaker.get_execution_role())
```

I get back an object of type `sagemaker.model.Model`.

I then seek to deploy the model via

```
fm_predictor = fm.deploy(instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge', initial_instance_count=1)
```

The output of this call is

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
```

But this returns a `NoneType` object that does not have a predict method. However, the model's endpoint is created.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my code samples, the deployment also does not have a relevant return value. But after the deployment, I have to create the predictor with the endpoint name:

```
endpoint_name = 'rf-scikit-endpoint-xxx'

model.deploy(
  instance_type='ml.c5.large',
  initial_instance_count=1,
  endpoint_name=endpoint_name)

predictor = sagemaker.sklearn.model.SKLearnPredictor(endpoint_name=endpoint_name)
```

Can you proceed in a similar way?

Comment: This solution is correct. It can be validated from the console too.... sagemaker>inference>endpoints... the new endpoint will appear there.